# python networkx colormap using absolute values

Tags: python, networkx, colormap

I am trying to set the node color of a network based on some numerical values. I noticed that, however, in the vector specifying the node_color, only the relative values matter if I use matplotlib colormap. What I want is that the color can reflect the absolute values.

For example, the following code generates a network whose nodes have different colors:

```
G = nx.cycle_graph(6)
edges = np.array(G.edges)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, iterations=200)

values = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.45,0.25,0.35,0.15])
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=values,cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
```

[image]

If we add a constant to the node_color vector like the following

```
values = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.45,0.25,0.35,0.15])+1
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=values,cmap=plt.cm.Reds)
```

I am expecting the colors of all the nodes to get darker, but the code returns an identical network. Is there a way to change this? I know in imshow we can use the argument "norm" to change it. But is there a simple way to do that for a networkx graph?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take look at the `vmin` and `vmax` parameters found in the [matplotlib.pyplot.scatter documentation](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.scatter.html).  As part of the documentation it states

> See networkx.draw_networkx() for a description of optional keywords.

Then, in [draw_newtorkx docs](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx.html#networkx.drawing.nx_pylab.draw_networkx) in Parameters, there are cmap and vmin, vmax for scaling.

```
G = nx.cycle_graph(6)
edges = np.array(G.edges)
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, iterations=200)

values = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.45,0.25,0.35,0.15])
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=values,cmap=plt.cm.Reds, vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

[image]

Now, let's modify your scaling factor a little bit so that you don't totally mask out the colors, instead of add 1, let's just add .25 since we aren't normalizing.

```
values = np.array([0.1,0.2,0.45,0.25,0.35,0.15])+.25
nx.draw(G, pos, node_color=values,cmap=plt.cm.Reds, vmin=0, vmax=1)
```

[image]